# GetText is returning a null string for a list box in a MFC program

Tags: c++, mfc

GetText is returning a null string for a list box in a MFC program:

```
void CMainDlg::OnLbnSelchangeLiPt()
{
    CListBox* lb;
    int idx, cnt;
    char* cstr;
    lb = (CListBox*)GetDlgItem(IDC_LI_PT);
    idx = lb->GetCurSel();
    cnt = lb->GetCount();
    if ((idx != LB_ERR) && (cnt > 0))
    {
        cstr = NULL;
        lb->GetText(idx, cstr);
...
```

The list box has one selected item.  What is wrong with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use stuff like `char a[32];`

You should be using:

```
CString sData;
int nSel = m_NameListBox.GetCurSel();
if (nSel != LB_ERR)
{
   m_NameListBox.GetText(nSel, sData);
}
```

you can also call `m_NameListBox.GetWindowText(sData);`

Please also use DataExchange MFC mechanism to map your control to a class variable:

```
void CSettingsGeneralPage::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_NAME_LISTBOX, m_NameListBox);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I needed to declare a character array with enough space to store the string:

```
void CMainDlg::OnLbnSelchangeLiPt()
{
    CListBox* lb;
    int idx, cnt;
    char cstr[32];
    lb = (CListBox*)GetDlgItem(IDC_LI_PT);
    idx = lb->GetCurSel();
    cnt = lb->GetCount();
    if ((idx != LB_ERR) && (cnt > 0))
    {
        lb->GetText(idx, cstr);
...
```

Comment: Much easier to do `CString szText; lb->GetText(idx, szText);`

Comment: BTW: you can simplify you test from `if ((idx != LB_ERR) && (cnt > 0))` to `if ((idx != LB_ERR))`. If `GetCount` returns 0 then  `GetCurSel` returns `LB_ERR` anyway.